# Manipulating a String with substring inside a query builder

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, query-builder

I have a Query Builder like this:

```
@Override
public List<ComplementoMaterial> findSomething(String codigoPrestador, String documentoPrestador, String numeroLote, String codDocumento, List<String> codigosServicos) {
    return builder().query(sqlComplementos())
        .set("codPrestador", codigoPrestador)
        .set("docPrestador", documentoPrestador)
        .set("numeroLote", numeroLote)
        .set("codDocumento", codDocumento)
        .set("codServicos", codigosServicos)
        .mapper(new RowMapper<ComplementoMaterial>() {
            @Override
            public ComplementoMaterial mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                ComplementoMaterial c = new ComplementoMaterial();
                c.setCodigoServico(rs.getLong("COD_SERVICO"));
                c.setRegistroAnvisa(rs.getString("COD_MATERIAL"));
                c.setReferencia(rs.getString("COD_REF_MATERIAL"));
                c.setAutorizacaoFuncionamento(rs.getString("NUM_AUT_FAT"));
                return c;
            }
        }).executeQuery();
}
```

When I set the **codigosServicos**, I wish to apply an substring to him, so for each index I need take just after the 4th char of that String. For example:

If in codigoServicos I have a List as follow ["Michael","Jackson","Lebron"], I need that the query take just ["ael", "son", "on"].

I already tried to add a just codigoServicos.substring(4), but as he is set as List, that is not possible. And I also cannot broke the set to add a for loop.

Any idea do help me?

Tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Java 8+? You can do it in one line with streams, like this:

```
.set("codServicos", codigosServicos.stream().map(s -> s.substring(4)).collect(Collectors.toList()))
```

Otherwsie you have to use a loop, sorry. You can, of course do the loop before you do `set`:

```
@Override
public List<ComplementoMaterial> findSomething(String codigoPrestador, String documentoPrestador, String numeroLote, String codDocumento, List<String> codigosServicos) {
    List<String> substrings = new List<>(codigosServicos.size());
    for (String name : codigosServicos) {
        substrings.add(name.substring(4));
    }
    return builder().query(sqlComplementos())
        .set("codPrestador", codigoPrestador)
        .set("docPrestador", documentoPrestador)
        .set("numeroLote", numeroLote)
        .set("codDocumento", codDocumento)
        // add list of substrings instead of the original list
        .set("codServicos", substrings)
        .mapper(new RowMapper<ComplementoMaterial>() {
            @Override
            public ComplementoMaterial mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                ComplementoMaterial c = new ComplementoMaterial();
                c.setCodigoServico(rs.getLong("COD_SERVICO"));
                c.setRegistroAnvisa(rs.getString("COD_MATERIAL"));
                c.setReferencia(rs.getString("COD_REF_MATERIAL"));
                c.setAutorizacaoFuncionamento(rs.getString("NUM_AUT_FAT"));
                return c;
            }
        }).executeQuery();
}
```